# C# MVVM cross Windows Phone 8 onNavigateTo and Init

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, mvvm

I got a project in C# , Windows Phone 8 MVVM cross.

I got a ViewModel and View off course. In the ViewModel I have an Init method to getting parameter from another ViewModel. In the View i written an onNavigatoTo and NavigateFrom events (overriden) to save and load the ViewModel State.

But, with OnNavigateTo event, the Init method doesn't execute. What's the problem?

Comment: can you post the code?

Answer (score 0):

Don't override the NavigatedTo if you want the Init method to work. Instead create a loaded event and do something like the following:

```
    #region Properties
    public ViewModel ViewModel
    {
        get { return (ViewModel)ViewModel; }
        set { base.ViewModel = value; }
    }
    #endregion

    #region Constructor
    public LoginView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Loaded += View_Loaded;
    }
    #endregion

    #region Events
    private void View_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ViewModel.SomeEventOrProperty //blah you get it
    }
    #endregion
```